# JOIN without double values

Tags: sql

I've got query

```
SELECT frst.Date,t1.Value
from
[ArchiveAnalog] frst
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Date,Value FROM
    [ArchiveAnalog] scnd
    WHERE scnd.ID = 1) t1
    ON t1.Date = frst.Date

order by frst.Date
```

but Join inserts values second time (not group with a main node)

if I do     GROUP BY frst.Date , I've got error that I can't use t1 Value with it.

How can I make this JOIN without adding additional rows ?

**Martin** I want to show full Date and Value only if ID = 1 , also then I want to add t2 value column etc like here :

```
SELECT frst.Date,t1.Value,t2.Value
from
[ArchiveAnalog] frst
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Date,Value FROM
    [ArchiveAnalog] scnd
    WHERE scnd.ID = 1) t1
    ON t1.Date = frst.Date
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Date,Value FROM
[ArchiveAnalog] scnd
WHERE scnd.ID = 2) t2
ON frst.Date = t2.Date
```

here I have x2 additional rows :S with doubling values, so I need to group them all with a some way.

Comment: So in the event of 2 matches in `[ArchiveAnalog] scnd` for a particular date which row do you want to use? Might be easier if you provide some example data. Not sure what you are trying to do here and the self join might not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
SELECT Date , 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID=1 THEN Value END) AS val1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID=2 THEN Value END) AS val2
FROM [ArchiveAnalog]
WHERE ID IN (1,2) /*<-- Not sure if you need this line without seeing your data*/
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need `DISTINCT` in the main query (if there's up to one row in `t1` that you need), or `GROUP BY`. If you use `GROUP BY`, you need to aggregate `t1.Value` (e.g. sum, concatenate etc.).